# My website is adding the home path to the address in the href

Tags: xhtml, href

My website is www.massasestefania.com.br
If you put the mouse over the link "Massas Estefania" on the end of the page you will see that the website is adding "www.massasestefania.com.br/" to the facebook address

My code is correct:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Massas-Estefania-1976106245948939">Massas Estefania</a>
```

but the generated path is:

www.massasestefania.com.br/www.facebook.com/Massas-Estefania-1976106245948939/

Anyone to help me to fix it?

Comment: Please
Put below code into your firefox address bar and press enter, or view page source, 
you must create your link after `http://` or `https://`
check again
    `view-source:data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<a%20href%3D"www.facebook.com%2FMassas-Estefania-1976106245948939%2F">Massas%20Estefania<%2Fa>`

Answer (score 0):

`www.facebook.com/Massas-Estefania-1976106245948939/` is *not* a valid URL.

`www.massasestefania.com.br` is *not* a valid URL.

---

`https://www.facebook.com/Massas-Estefania-1976106245948939/` *is* a valid URL.

`http://www.massasestefania.com.br/` *is* a valid URL.

---

URLs *must* start either with `https://` or `http://`. Browsers will *always* add anything else to the existing/current URL for the request.